# Get all users from active directory in NetCore 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap, novell

All the questions are related to the .NET framework but not to the .NET Core. I am looking for how to get the all users information from AD group in NETCORE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only plan on running your application in Windows, you can add [`Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility/2.0.1) to your project from NuGet, which includes the [`System.DirectoryServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices?view=netcore-2.0) namespace, so you can use [`DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry?view=netcore-2.0)/[`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=netcore-2.0) or the [`AccountManagement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement?view=netcore-2.0) namespace like you can in the full .NET Framework.

But if you plan on running this on other OS's, then I think the only option is Novell's library, as Steve mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using .Net Core 3.1 but you can use with .Net Core 2 as well.

First install the NuGet package "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement"

Then, you can use the code below to get all AD users:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement; 


public static List<ADUser> GetADUsers() {

    var myDomainUsers = new List<ADUser>();

    using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain"))
    {

        var userPrinciple = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

        using (var search = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrinciple))
        {
            foreach (UserPrincipal domainUser in search.FindAll().OrderBy(u => u.DisplayName))
            {
                var adUser = new ADUser() {
                    Description = domainUser.Description,
                    DisplayName = domainUser.DisplayName,
                    DistinguishedName = domainUser.DistinguishedName,
                    EmailAddress = domainUser.EmailAddress,
                    Name = domainUser.Name,
                    EmployeeId = domainUser.EmployeeId,
                    GivenName = domainUser.GivenName,
                    MiddleName = domainUser.MiddleName,
                    Surname = domainUser.Surname,
                    SamAccountName  = domainUser.SamAccountName
                }; 
                myDomainUsers.Add(adUser);
            } //foreach
        } //using
    } //using

    return myDomainUsers;

} //GetADGroups
```

Where I'm using the following ADUser class:

```
public class ADUser
{
    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

}
```

There are more attributes that you can extract from AD. Take a look in [UserPrincipal class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

I am connecting to Ldap using Novell.Directory.Ldap Package to authenticate my users.

Project.csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard" Version="2.3.8" />
```

Code.cs

```
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;

public bool LoginLdap(string username, string password)
{
    LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection();
    var loggedIn = false;
    try
    {
         connection.Connect(_config["Ldap:url"], LdapConnection.DEFAULT_PORT);
         connection.Bind(LdapConnection.Ldap_V3, _config["Ldap:domain"] + @"\" + username, password);
         loggedIn = true;
    }
    catch 
    {
         loggedIn = false;
    }
    connection.Disconnect();
    return loggedIn;
}
```

Config.json

```
"Ldap": {
"url": "[Ldap URL]",
"domain": "[Domain Name]"
 }
```